# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "id={id}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

---

There is a first API where I find products but if you need this product description it is in another API so now I am trying to get this description by first API id because if both API id match then you find the description. Where I am making a mistake? help me.**

**API Endpoint :**

```
` @GET("services/getProductDetails?id={id}")
    fun getProductDescription(@Path("id") id : Int) : Call<SearchResponce?>?`
```

```
 private fun setUpDescription(id : Int){


        val retrofit = ServerConnection.getConnection()
        if(retrofit!= null){
            apiEndPoint = retrofit.create(ApiEndPoint::class.java)
        }


            apiEndPoint.getProductDescription(id)!!.enqueue(object : Callback<SearchResponce?> {

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<SearchResponce?>,
                    response: Response<SearchResponce?>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val product = response.body()?.product
                        product?.let {
                            if (product.id == id){
                                binding.productDescription.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(product.description, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(this@ProductDetailsActivity, "Faild Data ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@ProductDetailsActivity, "Faild to get Category Data ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }


                override fun onFailure(call: Call<SearchResponce?>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@ProductDetailsActivity, "Faild to get Category Data ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
         }
```

**I am trying to get id bases product description**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Query](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html) instead of `Path`:

```kotlin
@GET("services/getProductDetails")
fun getProductDescription(
    @Query("id") id : Int
) : Call<SearchResponce?>?
```

This results in the following endpoint:

```
services/getProductDetails?id={id}
```

Comment: Thank you I don't have vote power otherwise i will vote you